# How to pass down value from view to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I have this view where I am trying to pass down an invoice object in hidden field to a controller and then submit it with a submit button.

```
@model IEnumerable<Invoice>;
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ShowModal", "Email", FormMethod.Post))
        {
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    @foreach (var invoice in Model)
                    {
                        <div class="col-12 bg-light d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-lg-2 mb-lg-5">
                            <div class="m-lg-2">Číslo faktury : @invoice.InvoiceNumber</div>
                            <div class="m-lg-2">Variabilní symbol : @invoice.VariableSymbol</div>
                            <div class="m-lg-2">Datum vytvoření : @invoice.DateCreated</div>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Stáhnout","Download",invoice,new { @class = "m-lg-2 btn btn-primary"})
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(_=>invoice, new {@type="hidden", @Value=invoice})
                            <input type="submit" value="Odeslat" class="m-lg-2 btn btn-secondary showmodal" />
              
                            @Html.ActionLink("Upravit","Edit",invoice,new { @class = "m-lg-2 btn btn-warning"})
                            @Html.ActionLink("Vymazat","Remove",invoice,new { @class = "m-lg-2 btn btn-danger"})
        
                        </div>
        
                    }
                </div>
        
        </div>
        }
```

But in the controller I dont receive the invoice object from some reason. Am I sending it the wrong way?

```
    public IActionResult ShowModal(Invoice invoice)
    {
        //string number = invoice.InvoiceNumber;
        return PartialView("_EmailPopup");
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the optional second argument for `PartialView`?

Comment: Yea, but I have no way to fill it as I am not receiving the invoice object

Comment: It does call the ShowModal() method? Is your Controller class EmailController?

Comment: Yes, it calls the ShowModal() method but the Invoice object comes with null values only

Comment: I think you should add a parameter to the `BeginForm` in the format `, new { invoice = invoice }` after the controller name "Email". The problem is that you don't have the invoice at that location. Could you move the `BeginForm` inside the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

It is allright to have multiple BeginForms on one page. So move the BeginForm inside the foreach loop and add an extra parameter to the BeginForm.

Your Controller should have the name EmailController.

```
    @model IEnumerable<Invoice>;
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        @foreach (var invoice in Model)
        {
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ShowModal", "Email", new {invoice = invoice}, FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="col-12 bg-light d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-lg-2 mb-lg-5">
                <div class="m-lg-2">Číslo faktury : @invoice.InvoiceNumber</div>
                <div class="m-lg-2">Variabilní symbol : @invoice.VariableSymbol</div>
                <div class="m-lg-2">Datum vytvoření : @invoice.DateCreated</div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Stáhnout","Download",invoice,new { @class = "m-lg-2 btn btn-primary"})
                @Html.TextBoxFor(_=>invoice, new {@type="hidden", @Value=invoice})
                <input type="submit" value="Odeslat" class="m-lg-2 btn btn-secondary showmodal" />
          
                @Html.ActionLink("Upravit","Edit",invoice,new { @class = "m-lg-2 btn btn-warning"})
                @Html.ActionLink("Vymazat","Remove",invoice,new { @class = "m-lg-2 btn btn-danger"})
    
            }
        }
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: The invoice object is still returning with null values, while when I debug the invoice object in view before its passed down to view, its populated with data, so I think there must be smth wrong with my syntax of passing it down

Comment: Add an attribute above your `ShowModal` method `[HttpPost]`

Comment: That didnt help

Comment: There might be a mixup with the names `invoice`. Try and change the foreach to `@foreach (var inv in Model)` and change the parameter to `new { invoice = inv }`. And of course every where you use `invoice` now.

Comment: Didnt work either, maybe its an issue of the hidden textbox?

Comment: No, I think it's a signature problem. The signature of the method must match exactly. You could also just use the ID instead of the whole Invoice because you still have to reread the data from the database. Try and change the `ShowModal(Invoice invoice)` to `ShowModal(int id)` and pass that as `new { id = invoice.Id }`. Do you have routes in your code?

Comment: I tried it except I am using Guid as the Id type, but that didnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250798/discussion-between-paul-sinnema-and-jenlee123).